# Extra 20px after html

Tags: html, css

I am finishing up a site [thebarn.psone.ca](http://thebarn.psone.ca) however there is a 20px white space at the bottom of the page that I cannot get rid of. It appears after the html and body elements. Help would be appreciated.

I will try to make this meaningful for the next person. It may help to know that this is a product of the drupal tao theme. My html looked like:

```
<html>
<body>
<div id='page'><div class='limiter clearfix'>
    <div class="content"></div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

My css:

```
.content {
    background: #CCCCCC;
    height: 1090px;
    width: 100%;    
}

.clearfix:after {
  display: block;
  height: 0;
  clear: both;
  visibility: hidden;
  content: ".";
}
```

This gave me grey 20px from bottom of the page and in firebug it looked like there was blank space after the html and body elements. However removing the content: "."; from the clearfix after as the below posts stated fixed the problem

Comment: Everything looks ok in Chrome.

Comment: Please add meaningful code and a problem description here. Don't just link 
to the site that needs fixing - otherwise, this question will lose any value
to future visitors once the problem is solved. Posting a 
[Short, Self Contained, Correct Example (SSCCE)](http://www.sscce.org/) 
that demonstrates your problem would help you get better answers. For more info, 
see [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to
it?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/) Thanks!

Comment: @mdesdev, no it doesnt. behind the footer is a gap

Comment: Yeah I see it now behind menu.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's due to your `div.limiter.clearfix:after`, see:

[image: here]

From what I can see, if you remove `content: ".";` it may fix it, otherwise you'll need to fiddle around with the `height`/`font-size`/`overflow`.

Answer (score 2):

Remove `content: ".";` from your `.clearfix:after` class.